# Inflate TextViews to LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

I want to inflate TextViews to LinearLayout.

I have a layout `activity_play_game` and java class `PlayGameActivity`.
Currently, for hardcoded number of TextViews it looks like this:

[image]

Now I tried to add number of TextViews according to the value of variable `numberForbiddenWords`. I added a piece of code that looks like this:

```
LinearLayout playGame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_play_game);
TextView temp;
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[numberForbiddenWords];
for(int i = 0; i < numberForbiddenWords; i++) {
    temp = new TextView(this);
    playGame.addView(temp);
    textViews[i] = temp;
}
```

And I have a method that adds textViews to the `activity_play_game`. Unfortunately now it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see it added TextViews at the bottom. So I removed all TextViews from  `activity_play_game` and added LinearLayout to inflate TextViews:

[image]

How can I inflate TextViews to this LinearLayout above the buttons?
I found that kind of solution:

activity_to_add_words:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In the java class:

```
final View addView;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_to_add_words,
        null);
final TextView textOut = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
```

but this is for a `View`, not `TextView`. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: you can't inflate `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` you can add it to `LinearLayout` with `addView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get reference of your `LinearLayout` `container_blue` and add `TextView's` to it.

**Try this:**

```
LinearLayout playGame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_blue);
TextView temp;
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[numberForbiddenWords];
for(int i = 0; i < numberForbiddenWords; i++) {
    temp = new TextView(this);
    temp.setText("TextView " + String.valueOf(i));
    temp.setId(i);
    temp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    playGame.addView(temp);
    textViews[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Year, it's working!
I had:
LinearLayout playGame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_play_game);
but it should be: 
LinearLayout playGame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_blue);
just different layout :)
Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

make one layout file using textview like this :

**layout_textview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/txt_spin"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="5dp"
android:textColor="#000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

then apply following code in your java file:

```
 LinearLayout playGame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_blue);      
 LayoutInflater li =(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View view = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_textview, null);
 TextView txt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_spin);
 playGame.addView(view);
```

Hope it works for you...happy coding..:)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your initial problem was about adding the items dynamically before the three buttons. If you want to add them before the three buttons simply call  `playGame.addView(temp,0);` This will always add the item to the first position in the layout.
If you need a specific order of the added views you need to play with the for loop to add them in the right order.